# Evaluate function in points inside half sphere and plot slides in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

I am trying to evaluate a function that depends on the radius from the center of a sphere to any point inside half a sphere.

I start by defining three arrays corresponding to the points along the radius, the elevation and azimuthal angles. In a `for` loop I compute the x, y and z coordinates to evaluate the function.

I am not sure if I am doing the mapping properly. I need to store the values of the evaluated function in a 3D matrix corresponding to the x, y, and z coordinates to plot slices in a postprocessing step, but I am stuck identifying how I can define the size of my function matrix.

In cartesian coordinates is really easy since one can link every coordinate with the dimension of the matrix. That's why I need some guidance in how I can slide the matrix since I don't have a 3D matrix with the cartesian coordinates. How I can construct this matrix from the spherical coordintaes?

Any help will be more than appreciated!

Here is my (unfruitful) attempt:

```
import numpy as np

beta = 1
rho = np.linspace(0, 1, 20)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 20)
theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, 10)

f = np.empty([len(theta), len(theta), len(phi)], dtype=complex)
for i in range(len(rho)):
    for j in range(len(phi)):
        for k in range(len(theta)):

            x = rho[i] * np.sin(theta[k]) * np.cos(phi[j])
            y = rho[i] * np.sin(theta[k]) * np.sin(phi[j])
            z = rho[i] * np.cos(theta[k])
            R = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
            f[k, i, j] = -1j*((z/R)/(z/R + beta)) * (np.exp(1j*k*R)/R)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo, the second dimension is again len(theta) isntead of len(rho). It should be

```
f = np.empty([len(theta), len(rho), len(phi)], dtype=complex)
```

Note also that, if I am not mistaken, you don't need `R` at all, it's just `rho[i]`.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I had a typo. Thanks for point it out! 
I think I need R since it changes with each value of ```rho, theta and phi```.

Comment: Print it out: you will see that locally R is equal to rho[i], regardless of j and k. It's the definition of rho.

Comment: You're right! Thanks!
Do you know maybe how I can solve the second part of my question?